# I'm trying to get the first Min value from a SQL database in android

Tags: android, sql

Sorry, I'm new. I have a table and need to get the column ID of the **first min value of the table**. The table is organized so the values keep decreasing until they get to 0 and all subsequent values are equal to zero.

It is possible for none of the values to be zero in which case Id need the last ID. It is important that I only have one return ID because of how I'm implementing it. This is the code I tried first but I'm getting an error.

I did not try to add the exception of there being no 0s here because I thought it might be easier to add an If statement in the implementation of the method I use.

The error I get confuses me because It seems like I can't use FIRST when I thought I could, but here it is:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: FIRST (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT FIRST (_id) FROM graph WHERE bac = 0;

**My code:**

```
    public int getWhereZero(){
    int zero = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT FIRST (" + COLUMN_ID
            + ") FROM " + TABLE_GRAPH
            +" WHERE " + COLUMN_BAC
            + " = 0;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        zero = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
        cursor.close();
    }
    return zero;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of `FIRST`. Probably you want something like `SELECT column_id FROM graph ORDER BY bac LIMIT 1`... (Sort by the value and pick the first row.)

Comment: Try: `SELECT Min(_id) as Minimum FROM graph WHERE bac = 0`. Then retrieve it so: `zero = cursor.getInt(0);` or so  `zero = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Minimum");`

Comment: Thanks a ton @MattGibson ! It works exactly as it should!

Comment: No problem. I've posted that as an answer. You might find it handy to download a SQLite client so you can have a play around with the language locally and get used to it -- even if you don't use the same database as the one on the Android device, you can build similar tables and try out different queries a lot more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a `FIRST()` function. However, you can limit the number of rows returned to one using `LIMIT`, so sorting by the desired order will get the row you need:

```
SELECT column_id FROM graph ORDER BY bac LIMIT 1;
```